How to make RuntimeInitializeOnLoadMethod ignore initialization before the first scene in the game?
In my game, object persistence between scene transitions is handled by an Initializer.cs script:
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public static class Initializer
{
    [RuntimeInitializeOnLoadMethod(RuntimeInitializeLoadType.BeforeSceneLoad)]

    public static void Execute()
    {
        Debug.Log("Loaded by the Persist Objects from the Initializer script");
        Object.DontDestroyOnLoad(Object.Instantiate(Resources.Load("PersistObjects")));
    }
}

However, since PersistObjects prefab includes various managers, cameras and the player, I don't want it to be loaded into the first scene (i.e. the main menu).
Ideally, I want to have a way to check (by name) what scene is going to be loaded, and based on it, decide whether or not to spawn PersistObjects into the scene.
